# 2 dropdown-menu and it only shows the content of one of them

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, web, bootstrap-4

I'm doing a website and I encountered the following issue:

I want to show a list of months of different years (2017 and 2018), but the web browser only shows the months of one of the years in both options.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```js
function mostrarTablaTiempoReal() {
        document.getElementById("tabla_tiempo_real").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("tabla_historico").style.display = "none";
    }
    
    function mostrarTablaHistorico() {
        document.getElementById("tabla_tiempo_real").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("tabla_historico").style.display = "block";
    }
    
    function recuperarBotonTiempoReal() {
        document.getElementById("boton_tiempo_real").style.cursor = "hand";
        document.getElementById("boton_tiempo_real").style.opacity = 1;
    }
    
    function ocultarBotonTiempoReal() {
        document.getElementById("boton_tiempo_real").style.cursor = "not-allowed";
        document.getElementById("boton_tiempo_real").style.opacity = 0.6;
    }
    
    function bajarFichero() {
        
    }
    
    function subirFichero() {
        
    }
    
    function interpretarFichero() {
        
    }
    
    function crearFichero() {
        
    }
```

```css
<style>
            .canvas {
                        background-color: blue; 
                        width: 100%;
                        height: auto;
                    }
            .disabled {
                    opacity: 0.6;
                    cursor:not-allowed;
                    }
            .boton-enlace:hover{
                cursor:pointer; cursor: hand; 
            }
        </style>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Idioma de la página-->

<html lang="es">
    <!--Cabecera, contiene información sobre el documento-->
    <head>
        <!--Título de la página-->
        <title>Ahorro</title>
        <!--Tipo de caracteres que usamos-->
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <!--Mobile-first-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!--Añadimos Bootstrap-->
        <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!--Añadimos jQuery-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--Añadimos Popper JS-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <!--Añadimos JavaScript-->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!--Añadimos iconos de Google-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <!--Estilo personalizado para la página-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <!--Fuentes personalizadas para la página-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
        <style>
            .canvas {
                        background-color: blue; 
                        width: 100%;
                        height: auto;
                    }
            .disabled {
                    opacity: 0.6;
                    cursor:not-allowed;
                    }
            .boton-enlace:hover{
                cursor:pointer; cursor: hand; 
            }
        </style>
        <!--Script con acciones propias-->
        <script src="/elementos/acciones.js"></script>
    </head>
    <!--Cuerpo, contiene los elementos visibles del contenido de la página-->
    <body style="background-image: url(/elementos/Fondo1.jpg);">
        <div class="container-fluid" >
            <!--Contenedor botones de la izquierda-->
            <div class="col-sm-2" style="float: left; top:10px;">
                <!--Botón para ir atrás (BOTÓN ATRÁS)-->
                <a href="index.html">
                    <button style="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                        <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 22px; color:white; float: left;">arrow_back</i>
                        Atrás
                    </button>
                </a>
                <!--FIN BOTÓN ATRÁS-->
                <br>
                <!--Botón para mostrar los datos de tiempo real (BOTÓN TIEMPO REAL)-->
                    <button style="button" id="boton_tiempo_real" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block disabled" onclick="mostrarTablaTiempoReal(); ocultarBotonTiempoReal();">
                        <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 22px; color:white;">timer</i>
                        Consumo<br>tiempo real
                    </button>
                <!--FIN BOTÓN TIEMPO REAL-->
            </div>
            <!--FIN CONTENEDOR BOTONES IZQUIERDA-->
            <!--Tabla del centro para datos tiempo real-->
            <div class="col-sm-8" id="tabla_tiempo_real" style="float: left; top:100px; display: block;">
                <div class="card mb-4">
                    <div class="card-block">
        <h3 class="card-title">Datos de consumo</h3>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Datos en tiempo real</h6>
                        <hr/>
                    <div class="canvas-wrapper">
            <canvas class="main-chart" id="bar-chart" height="157" width="472" style="width: 472px; height: 157px;">
                        </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Tabla del centro para datos históricos-->
            <div class="col-sm-8" id="tabla_historico" style="float: left; top:100px; display: none;">
                <div class="card mb-4">
                    <div class="card-block">
        <h3 class="card-title">Datos de consumo</h3>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Histórico</h6>
                        <hr/>
                    <div class="canvas-wrapper">
            <canvas class="main-chart" id="bar-chart" height="157" width="472" style="width: 472px; height: 157px;">
                        </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--FIN TABLA CENTRO-->
            <!--Botón que muestra el histórico de consumo (BOTÓN HISTÓRICO)-->
            <div class="col-sm-2" style="float: right; top:100px;">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 22px; color:white;">list</i>
                    Histórico
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" style="background-color: transparent; border: none;">
                        <!--Botón 2018-->
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton_2018" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        2018
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton_2018">
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Enero</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Febrero</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Marzo</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Abril</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Mayo</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Junio</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Julio</button>
                        </div>
                        <!--FIN BOTÓN 2018-->
                        <!--Botón 2017-->
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton_2017" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        2017
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton_2017">
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Enero</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Febrero</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Marzo</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Abril</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Mayo</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Junio</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Julio</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Agosto</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Septiembre</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Octubre</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Noviembre</button>
                            <button class="dropdown-item boton-enlace" type="button" onclick="recuperarBotonTiempoReal(); mostrarTablaHistorico();">Diciembre</button>
                        </div>
                        <!--FIN BOTÓN 2017-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--FIN BOTÓN HISTÓRICO-->
            
        </div>
    </body>

</html>`enter code here`
```

PD: I attach two images of what is showing the web browser.

[2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbDQP.png)

[2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG0LN.png)

Comment: You should add the js and css code so that we can help you. The html only is not enough (give only the css and js that have to do with your html)

Comment: Sorry, I added all the code now

Comment: Put your code as snippet in order to us can edit and solve it, thx

Comment: Moreover, i can't find any tabla_tiempo_real for example on your html, so the code is incomplete... You need to provide a usable snippet

Comment: Sorry for all of this... I am new in this web and I don't know how to insert the information... Hope that this is well edited now.